# Trocar valor de uma varivel de outro componente Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Ola, eu tenho um component que se chama errorLog, dentro dele tem um metodo chamada LogOut, que e chamada quando eu clico em 1 botão de logOut, porem apos deslogar você e redirecionado a pagina de login, porem eu queria exibir um texto nessa tela de login que so e exibido apos ser deslogado, então, no meu templateHTML do meu component de login criei esse seguinte codigo:

```
<div *ngIf="deslogado" class="alert alert-warning">
          <span>Você foi deslogado</span>
</div>
```

então so ira aparecer essa div quando a variavel 'deslogado' for TRUE, então como eu faço para dizer no meu component que a variavel 'deslogar' do component login e true? para quando ser redirecionado o *ngIf dar true?

Comment: Editei seu código e pergunta e deixei mais intuitivo para que respostas mais elaboradas apareçam.

Answer (score 0):

Para compartilhar variáveis entre componentes o Angular recomenda a utilização de serviços.

Serviço são singletons, ou seja, somente uma instância existe durante o ciclo de vida da aplicação e devem ser utilizados para manter o estado de informações entre componentes.

Um exemplo clássico na utilização de serviços é justamente manter a informação do usuário logado.

```
@Injectable()
export class AccountService {
  account?: Account

  login(): void {
    account = { id: 1111, name: 'Marcelo' }
  }

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return !!account
  }

  loggout(): void {
    account = undefined
  }
}
```

No serviço acima utilizamos a membro de classe `account` para armazenar a informação do usuário logado.

O método `login` deve executar seu processo de login e armazenar o resultado na variável account.

O método `isLoggedIn` valida a informação da variável `account` e retorna `true` caso ela tenha sido preenchida, ou seja o usuário esteja logado.

O método `loggout` apenas configura a variável `account` como `undefined` ou seja removendo a informação do usuário logado.

Após definido o serviço, é preciso injeta-lo no seu component para exibir a informação, portanto conforme entendi faça o seguinte

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login'
  ...
})
export class PaginaLoginComponent {

  constructor(
    private accountService: AccountService
  ) { }

  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.accountService.isLoggedIn()
  }

}
```

e no template do component `PaginaLoginComponent`

```
<div *ngIf="isLoggedIn()" class="alert alert-warning">
  <span>Você foi deslogado</span>
</div>
```

Pronto, espero ter ajudado, lembre-se para compartilhar informações que dizer respeito ao estado global da aplicação utilizamos serviços do Angular.

[]s

Answer (score 0):

Você pode também passar uma flag na url

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/core';

@Component(...)
export class SeuComponent {
    public justLogout = false;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
            (params: any) => {
                if (params['logout'] === 'true') {
                    this.justLogout = true;
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

No seu template

```
<div *ngIf="justLogout" class="alert alert-warning">
    <span>Você foi deslogado</span>
</div>
```

Daí é so redirecionar assim

```
http://sua-url/login?logout=true
```

Ou no template usando o routerLink

```
<a routerLink="/login" [queryParams]="{logout: true}">link</a>
```

ou ainda por navegação imperativa

```
import { Router } from '@angular/core';

constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {}

goToLogin() {
    this.route.navigate(['/login'], {queryParams: {'logout': 'true'}});

}
```

Referência:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7mc184O4x0